# Prohibit MS Word from automatically changing the Replace input in the AutoCorrect Window

Tags: microsoft-word

I noticed that in the MS Word AutoCorrect window, the Replace field seems to be not case-sensitive in a forcible way. For example, if I already have a pair of Replace and With as (CA, California), when I want to make another pair as (ca2=, Ca2+), the window prohibits me from typing the "ca" part of the "ca2=" and will always automatically change it into "CA2=". This is really annoying and persistent on different computers. Is there a way to create such a new pair and type in "ca2=" as it is? Thanks!

Ps: the "Ca2+" I want to replace into is the calcium ion so it has some formating--the "2+" should be upper

Comment: When you get this, backspace and try typing again (maybe even a couple of times) and then, assuming you have what you want, right click on it and add it to your dictionary. That should prevent future issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how:

```
If Selection.Type = wdSelectionNormal Then 
 AutoCorrect.Entries.AddRichText "NewText", Selection.Range 
Else 
 MsgBox "You need to select some text." 
End If
```

Pairs created by this will appear in the AutoCorrect dialog.
Ref: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.autocorrectentries.addrichtext

Answer (score 0):

Two ways I can think of overcoming this problem ...

1. Type ca2 and let it change the name to CA2, but then go back and replace the uppercase letters with lowercase. This works because with the addition of the number 2 the name is different than any other stored name.
2. Use a VBA macro instead of the built-in AutoCorrect dialog. See below:

Sub AddAutoCorrects()

```
    Dim entry As String, str() As String
    entry = InputBox("Type AC name followed by replacement value." & vbCr & _
                "Separate each with a | vertical line symbol.", "AuthorTec™")
    str = Split(entry, "|")
    Word.AutoCorrect.Entries.Add str(0), str(1)

End Sub
```

Comment: Method 1: Word doesn't allow me to replace the CA with ca--it will automatically change it back. Method 2: this doesn't really work because the "Ca2+" that I want to replace into actually have some formats, aka the calcium ion.

Comment: Oh I figured it out. Use AddRichText. I made a separate answer below. Thanks!